# don't understand this proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Let $d$ be a correspondence where $\emptyset \neq d(S) \subseteq S$ and two properties: A and B.

A) If $y, y' \in A \cap B$ and $y \in d(A)$, then $y \in d(B)$ whenever $y' \in d(B)$

B) If $Y \subseteq Z$, then $d(Z) \cap Y \subseteq d(Y)$

I'm having problems understanding this proof that shows that A implies B:

Let $y \in d(Z) \cap Y$. Since $d(Y) \neq \emptyset $, fix $y' \in d(Y) \subseteq Z$. Then, $y,y' \in Y \cap Z$ and by A) happens that $y \in d(Y)$.

This is a very short proof, but I don't get the logic behind it. It confuses me as it starts with property B (1), then uses A(2), and finally  use property B again (3).

(1) Let $y \in d(Z) \cap Y$. Since $d(Y) \neq \emptyset $, fix $y' \in d(Y) \subseteq Z$

(2)Then, $y,y' \in Y \cap Z$

(3) happens that $y \in d(Y)$.

I mean, if we are trying to proof that A implies B, as we are not using transposition shouldn't we start with A and then reach B?

EDIT

Thanks, the proof is much clearer this way.
For the development of the proof, I understand the importance of choosing $y, y'$ s.t. $y \in d(Z) \cap Y$ and $y' \in d(Y)$.

It's obvious that we need to start with $y \in d(Z) \cap Y$ since we need to get to $y \in d(Y)$, but, for me, it is hard to come up with the idea of choosing a $y'$ s.t. $y' \in d(Y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof does start by assuming (A); the author simply takes it for granted that the reader will realize this. Here’s an expanded version of exactly the same argument.

> Assume (A). We wish to show that if $Y\subseteq Z$, then $d(Z)\cap Y\subseteq d(Y)$, so assume that $Y\subseteq Z$. One way to show that $d(Z)\cap Y\subseteq d(Y)$ is to show that if $y\in d(Z)\cap Y$, then $y\in d(Y)$, so suppose that $y\in d(Z)\cap Y$. By hypothesis $d(Y)\ne\varnothing$, so there is some $y'\in d(Y)$. Since $d(Y)\subseteq Y\subseteq Z$ by hypothesis, $y'\in Y\cap Z$. Moreover, $y\in d(Z)\subseteq Z$, and $y\in Y$, so $y\in Y\cap Z$ as well. Thus, we have $y,y'\in Y\cap Z$, $y\in d(Z)$, and $y'\in d(Y)$, so (A) implies that $y\in d(Y)$. Since $y$ was an arbitrary member of $d(Z)\cap Y$, it follows that $d(Z)\cap Y\subseteq d(Y)$, as desired.

Does that make the flow of logic a bit clearer?

Comment: Thanks, the proof is much clearer this way.
For the development of the proof, I understand the importance of choosing $y, y'$ s.t. $y \in d(Z) \cap Y$ and $y' \in d(Y)$. 

It's obvious that we need to start with $y \in d(Z) \cap Y$ since we need to get to $y \in d(Y)$, but, for me, it is hard to come up with the idea of choosing a $y'$ s.t. $y' \in d(Y)$ @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @user3889486: You’re welcome. One way to arrive at $y'$ is to realize that we want to use (A) somehow to get $y\in d(Y)$. (A) guarantees that $y\in d(Y)$ ***if*** we can find a $y'\in d(Y)$ such that both $y$ and $y'$ are in $Y\cap Z$. This would be simplest if it turned out that any old $y'\in d(Y)$ would work, since we know that there has to be one. And if we try it, simply starting with some $y'\in d(Y)$, it turns out that all of the necessary pieces fall into place.

Comment: I have tried solving similar proofs, and your explanation has definitely helped me. Thanks again @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @user3889486: I’m glad to hear it. You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your original question: [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott) did a great job clarifying the proof you quoted.

However, I'd like to show a proof in a different style, in answer to your later note that "for me, it is hard to come up with the idea of choosing a $\;y'\;$ s.t. $\;y' \in d(Y)\;$." So let's try to prevent rabbits being pulled out of hats.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

In this style of proof (for background and details on notation see, e.g., Edsger W. Dijkstra's [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html)) one tries to use shape of the formulas to guide the proof.  So we might as well start with writing our task a bit more formally: given
\begin{align}
& \tag{da} d(S) \not= \emptyset & \\
& \tag{db} d(S) \subseteq S & \\
& \tag{A} \langle \forall y,y' : y,y' \in A \cap B \;\land\; y \in d(A) \;\land\; y' \in d(B) : y \in d(B) \rangle & \\
& \tag{B1} Y \subseteq Z
\end{align}
for any sets $\;S, A, B\;$ and for some specific sets $\;Y, Z\;$, we are asked to prove
$$
\tag{B2} d(Z) \cap Y \subseteq d(Y)
$$

Our conclusion $\ref{B2}$ is cast in terms of sets, while the main hypothesis $\ref A$ is mostly given in terms of elements.  Therefore we have two options: we can either first transform $\ref A$ to sets, and then do the proof at the set level; or we can translate $\ref{B2}$ to elements and do the proof on the element level.  I've here chosen to do the latter, since I am more familiar with the laws of logic than the corresponding laws of set theory; but the choice seems fairly subjective.

---

So we start rewriting the conclusion $\ref{B2}$ in terms of elements, and see where that leads us:
$$\calc
    \tag{B2}
    d(Z) \cap Y \subseteq d(Y)
\op=\hint{expand definitions of $\;\subseteq\;$ and $\;\cap\;$}
    \langle \forall y : y \in d(Z) \;\land\; y \in Y : y \in d(Y) \rangle
\op=\hints{$\;Y = Z \cap Y\;$ by $\ref{B1}$; reorder}
       \hints{-- this makes the formula look more like}
       \hint{$\ref A$ (with $\;Z,Y\;$ substituted for $\;A,B\;$)}
    \langle \forall y : y \in Z \cap Y \;\land\; y \in d(Z) : y \in d(Y) \rangle
\op\when\hints{generalize, assuming there is some $\;y'\;$}
       \hints{for which $\;y' \in Z \cap Y\;$ and $\;y' \in d(Y)\;$}
       \hint{-- this brings us directly to $\ref A$}
    \langle \forall y,y' : y,y' \in Z \cap Y \;\land\; y \in d(Z) \;\land\; y' \in d(Y) : y \in d(Y) \rangle
\op=\hint{by $\ref A$ with $\;A,B := Z,Y\;$}
    \true
\endcalc$$
All that is left now is to prove that there is indeed a $\;y'\;$ for which $\;y' \in Z \cap Y \;\land\; y' \in d(Y)\;$:
$$\calc
    \langle \exists y' :: y' \in Z \cap Y \;\land\; y' \in d(Y) \rangle
\op=\hint{simplify using $\;Y = Z \cap Y\;$ by $\ref{B1}$}
    \langle \exists y' :: y' \in Y \;\land\; y' \in d(Y) \rangle
\op=\hint{RHS implies LHS, by $\ref{db}$}
    \langle \exists y' :: y' \in d(Y) \rangle
\op=\hint{by $\ref{da}$ and the definition of $\;\emptyset\;$}
    \true
\endcalc$$
And that completes the proof.